# Post parameters in ajax to my controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have a few buttons on my index page that are not in a form and that act as filters for markers on a map.

I am trying to post the filter choices as parameters to my index action.

How do I do something like this?

```
 function filterchanged()
  {

  $.post('/index.html.erb', { filter1: 'value1', filter2: 'false' }, function(result) {
      alert('successfully posted filter1=value1&key2=filter2 to index.html.erb');
    });
   ....
}
```

My index controller action looks something like this:

```
 def index

      if params.has_key?(:filter1) 
        if params[:filter2]
          @posts = Post.typeA
        else
          @posts = Post.typeB
      end

      else 
        @posts = Post.all
      end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 2 hidden fields to the form with names equal to filter1 and filter2 (so the form passes them to your controller action.  Use an onClick event for each button to update the respective hidden field values, toggling the values if need be.  You may default the hidden fields to 0 or false or whatever you'd like.

Then, in your controller action check for the value of the filter variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your path for index action is really weird.
`/index.html.erb` is the file name of your index view and is not intended to be used in this way.

To point to that action you must use route paths.

Open a terminal and run `rake routes` and check the correct route for your index action.
All the routes are setted in `/config/routes.rb`

I think you should take a look to this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html